# Android right to left textview sliding animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, slide

I am currently building a clothing store app and one feature I want to implement is a kind of information banner along the top of the home fragment. I'm relatively new to using animations but I'm pretty much sure that it's the best option.

I have a list of strings such as the following:

```
val information = listOf("Information 1", "Information 2", "Information 3")
```

What I would like to do is have each string slide into the fragment from the right to the center (take 2 seconds), stay in the center for 3 seconds, then slide off screen to the left in 2 seconds whilst the next information is sliding in. An important point is I want this to repeat forever (as long as you stay on the Home fragment).

It would look something like this:

```
1) Left side of screen -> |                  Information 1                  | <- Right side of screen
2) Left side of screen -> | Information 1                     Information 2 | <- Right side of screen
3) Left side of screen -> |                  Information 2                  | <- Right side of screen
```

I expect to have to use two different animation files for this so I wrote the following:

Right to center

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="3000">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Center to left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="3000">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

I have no idea how to actually get this to work unfortunately and would really appreciate some assistance.

**EDIT**

I have used view binding and a view model that stores the information as `LiveData<List<String>>` and the setting of the animations is done in the `onCreateView` function.

The way I do it is like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    homeViewModel.setBannerInformation(listOf(
        "Information 1", 
        "Information 2", 
        "Information 3"
    ))

    homeViewModel.bannerInformation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { informationList ->
        val rightToCenter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(binding.bannerInformation.context, R.anim.banner_information_animation_right_to_center)
        val centerToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(binding.bannerInformation.context, R.anim.banner_information_animation_center_to_left)

        binding.bannerInformation.text = informationList.first()
        binding.bannerInformation.startAnimation(rightToCenter)
        binding.bannerInformation.startAnimation(centerToLeft)
    })

    return binding.root
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example have you managed to get a single `TextView` to animate? There are plenty of tutorials out there for that.

Comment: I have yes, however, it slides off screen after 3 seconds and then nothing happens. No new animation or anything

Comment: Definitely make sure you include your code in the question then. At the moment you're just asking us to write it all for you which is not something that should be encouraged.

Comment: Question has been edited with my basic failure of an implementation ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issue which seems like a hacky solution but so far it works.

Firstly, create an animation resource file that does the animation you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="2000"/>

    <translate
        android:startOffset="3500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Next, create a function that will define the animation and changes to occur

```
private fun animateInformationBanner(information: List<String>, start: Int = 0) : Animation {
    var index = start
    val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(binding.bannerInformation.context, R.anim.banner_information_animation)
    animation.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            binding.bannerInformation.text = information[index % information.size]
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            index++
            binding.bannerInformation.text = null
            binding.bannerInformation.startAnimation(animation)
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })

    return animation
}
```

Finally, apply the animation to the TextView

```
homeViewModel.bannerInformation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { informationList ->
    binding.bannerInformation.startAnimation(animateInformationBanner(informationList))
})
```